# Large number of erroneous Content Security Policy (CSP) warnings in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, content-security-policy

I'm getting a huge number of these warnings in the error console in Firefox:

> Warning: Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource: An attempt to apply inline style sheets has been blocked

And others like this:

> Warning: Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource: An attempt to apply inline style sheets has been blocked
>
> Source Code: position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:1px;height:1px;padding:0;margin:0;border:5px solid #000;display:block;

Here's my complete Content Security Policy header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; media-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; font-src 'none'; connect-src 'none';
```

And here's my complete test page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Testing.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This seems erroneous to me. There are no inline styles or scripts. Is this a bug in Firefox? Am I doing something wrong? My concern is that these errors would result in my server being flooded with pointless CSP violation reports when I enable the reporting.

Comment: runs just fine on chrome - do you really need to use xhtml??

Comment: The page loads, but I get warnings in the error console, which would result in my server being flooded with CSP reports when I enable reporting. Re: your question, is use of XHTML actually relevant? It's my preferred markup (it makes the most semantic sense to me) so yes, I'd prefer to stick with it.

Comment: try switching it from "xhtml-strict.dtd" to xhtml-transitional.dtd or xhtml-frameset.dtd

Comment: disable all browser plugins ? Or one by one to find the offender, sounds like a 'add in' problem

Comment: @RobSedgwick The error doesn't seem to appear in safe mode, so you may be correct.